# Eclipse Design Tab detects wrong Java

Tags: java, eclipse

When I click on the design tab I get this error:

```
Incompatible Java Versions

Eclipse is running under 1.7, but this Java project has a 1.8 Java compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version.
```

I've checked in window>preferences that:

1. >java>compiler is set to 1.8
2. >java>installed JREs has a 1.8 JDK as the default

Have I missed something?

Comment: Apparently you actually started eclipse with Java 1.7; what is the result of `java -version` on the command line?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch that gives me "1.8.0_31"

Comment: Do you have a "JAVA_HOME" set? Or in fact Java 1.7 installed? What platform? What version of eclipse?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch looks like JAVA_HOME is set to the java 7 one, will this require a restart?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch looks like a restart isn't necessary, Changing and restarting eclipse worked. Thank you, post an answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> looks like JAVA_HOME is set to the java 7 one, will this require a restart?

You're actually executing eclipse with Java 7, you can update `JAVA_HOME` to point to Java 8, and then restart eclipse (not your computer).